# Higgs Production: Gluon Gluon Fusion

Tags: standard-model, higgs, gluons

(i) Why is the virtual top-loop not forbidden in the process of gluon gluon fusion where we have the "triangle" of virtual top quarks? Wouldn't the Higgs boson need colour for the process to be allowed?

(ii) Why couldn't a $Z^{0}$ boson be produced by the same mechanism? [image]

Comment: I recommend https://feynman.aivazis.com/ for generating images of Feynman diagrams

Comment: Thanks, good for the future!

Comment: i)  when the two gluons are in a color singlet state, the product is colorless: H, Z, etc..  ii) the gluon-gluon-fusion  to virtual Z diagram is an important part of calculations, cf Fig 1 of [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP06(2015)065).

Comment: (i) I am confused. There is no colour singlet state for the gluon, which would correspond to $G_{9} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left( r\bar{r} + g\bar{g} + b\bar{b}\right)$, right? (ii) Wouldn't this be called associate production then?

Comment: Color octets are self-conjugate, so you may saturate two of them into a singlet, $\lambda^a_{ij} \lambda^a_{ji}$.